# Openslide: Remove “label” image for Philips TIFF files

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, openslide

I'm using openslide-python to read whole slide images in the [Philips format](https://openslide.org/formats/philips/). I am trying to anonymize the data by removing the label associated image by deleting/replacing this:
`slide.associated_images["label"]`
However it raises:
`TypeError: '_AssociatedImageMap' object does not support item assignment`
I know this is because Openslide is a reading not writing library, however I can't find a solution to remove the labels for Philips format.

Comment: Have you tried this python script that removes slide labels from images using openslide-python? https://github.com/bgilbert/anonymize-slide

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish this task?